# Checking whether value is greater or lesser than value entered by user using Angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have an input field which a user must input a value that is within the amount pulled from the database. The input field value entered by the user must satisfy either the minimum, maximum, or default value brought back from the database. So if the minimum value brought back from the database is *4500.25* then the user's input if below that minimum amount should display an error msg (something like ng-messages).

---

**View**

---

[image]

### **HTML**

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label>Loan Amount</label>
    <div class="input-group">
        <input blur-to-currency type="text" class="form-control" name="loan_amount" ng-model="loan.loan_amount" ng-pattern="/(^(1{0,1}|([1-9][0-9]*))(\.[0-9]{1,4})?$)/" min="{{productDetails.minimum_amt}}" required>
            <span class="input-group-addon">JMD</span>
                                </div>
            <span class="tiny">Min: {{productDetails.minimum_amt | currency}}</span>&nbsp;
            <span class="tiny">Max: {{productDetails.maximum_amt | currency}}</span>&nbsp;
            <span class="tiny">Default: {{productDetails.default_amt | currency}}</span>&nbsp;

            <div ng-messages="newLoanForm.loan_amount.$error" ng-if="newLoanForm.loan_amount.$dirty">
                <div ng-message="required">
                    <span class="error-msgs">Please enter a loan amount</span>
                </div>

                <div ng-message="pattern">
                    <span class="error-msgs">Loan amount must be a numerical value</span>
                </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

---

**Object Literal**

---

[image]

In the above html I try to use **min** however that does not work and **ng-minlength** would not work either. Can someone assist me in maybe creating a directive or something else that will help me achieve my goal. Thanks in advance.

Comment: did you try changing it to input type="number"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think min should work but your input type should be `number`
try below

```
<input blur-to-currency type="number" class="form-control" name="loan_amount" ng-model="loan.loan_amount" ng-pattern="/(^(1{0,1}|([1-9][0-9]*))(\.[0-9]{1,4})?$)/" min="{{productDetails.minimum_amt}}" required>
```

Checkout the plunker as well http://plnkr.co/edit/HTBFNCLf0a6RXOzaABVU?p=preview